# Laravel 5 - Mongodb query builder installation

Tags: php

Every time when i am running "composer require jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0" this command in my command prompt. I am just getting below error can any one suggest. Thanks in advance.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

D:\XAMPP\htdocs\library>composer require jenssegers/mongodb
Using version ^3.0 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable b
y mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].

```
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable b
```

y mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].

```
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.0.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable b
```

y mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1].

```
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP ext
```

ension mongodb is missing from your system.

```
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP ext
```

ension mongodb is missing from your system.

```
- Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.0 -> satisfiable by jensseg
```

ers/mongodb[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:

```
- D:\XAMPP\php\php.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PH
P in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit more information about this solution